# Why do calls to _Noreturn generate real calls instead of jumps?

Tags: gcc, assembly, clang, x86-64, icc

I looked at

```
//#define _Noreturn //<= uncomment to see jmp's change to call's

_Noreturn void ext(int,char const*);

__attribute((noinline))
_Noreturn void intern(int X)
{
    ext(X,"X"); //jmp unless ext is _Noreturn
}


void do_intern(void)
{
    intern(0);  //jmp unless intern is _Noreturn
}

int do_int_intern(void)
{
    intern(0);   //call in either case, 
                 //would've expected a jmp if intern is _Noreturn 
    return 42;   //erased if intern is _Noreturn
}
```

in 
https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/MoT-LK and I noticed all gcc, clang, and icc generate real calls (`call` in x86_64) for calls to a `_Noreturn` function even though without the `_Noreturn` the call would have been a direct jump (`jmp` in x86_64).

Why is this?

Comment: Perhaps GCC assumes that noreturn functions might want to backtrace the stack to show where they were called from?  Or maybe compiler internals just miss the tailcall optimization for a function that's supposed to not return.  But yes, good question; it wastes a `sub rsp,8` in the caller.  I assume it's the same with GNU C `__attribute__((noreturn))`?

Answer (score 0):

For your examples, when compiled for x86_64, a JMP instruction couldn't be substituted for a CALL instruction as the stack won't be properly aligned.  The callee expects the stack to be 16-byte aligned plus 8 for the return value.

Your example code, when compiled with `-Os`, generates this assembly on all the compilers in your godbolt link:

```
do_intern:
        push    rax          ; ICC uses RSI here instead
        xor     edi, edi
        call    intern
```

To change the call into a JMP it would have to either add additional instruction to push a fake return value on the stack or undo the stack alignment made at the top of the function:

```
do_intern:
        push    rax
        xor     edi, edi
        push    rax            ; or pop rax 
        jmp     intern
```

Now if the compiler were really smart it could realize that there really isn't need to align the stack at the start of the function, so no need to undo it or push a fake return value:

```
do_intern:
        xor     edi, edi
        jmp     intern
```

But the compilers aren't smart enough to do this.  Probably because it won't work in the general case where the function allocates variables on the stack and because there's rarely anything to be gained by improving the performance of calling functions that can never return.

In the tail-call case without _Noreturn, the CALL instruction could potentially be called multiple times during the execution of the program, so it can be worthwhile treating as a special case.  With _Noreturn the CALL instruction can only be called once during the execution of the program (unless `intern` ends up making a recursive call to `do_intern`).  Despite the similarity of the two cases, it would require new code to recognize the _Noreturn special case.

---

Note for GCC at least, it turns recognizing the _Noreturn special case is a lot harder than I initially thought, as [explained by Richard Henderson on the GCC bugs mailing list](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2000-10/msg00180.html):

> This is the fault of my noreturn patch -- sibcalls to noreturn
>   functions no longer got an edge to EXIT, which meant that the code
>   intended to insert sibcall_epilogue patterns didn't.
>
> It's a quandry: we need the more accurate CFG for the "control reaches
>   end of non-void function" test.  But then if we brute force search for
>   sibcalls to insert the sibcall_epilogue  patterns, we'll wind up with
>   flow2 warning about wanting to delete dead epilogue code (the loads
>   for the call-saved registers are dead becase we don't return).
>
> I think the best way to solve this is to not create sibcalls to
>   noreturn functions. [...]

The term "sibcalls" refer to "sibling" calls, where a tail-call can use a jump instruction instead of a call instruction.

This is the reason why, at least initially, the optimization you're expecting was never (correctly) implemented in GCC. The fact that in most cases it would be better to have more accurate backtraces when non-returning functions like `abort` are called, seems to be a post hoc justification, though one that's probably significantly contributed to the optimization never being implemented in GCC, as well as clang and ICC.

Comment: This is argument doesn't really hold up.  The `sub rsp,8` or dummy push is only there in the first place to satisfy the stack alignment requirement for a call that's not a `jmp` tailcall.  Of course you can't *just* replace `call` with `jmp` but I don't think the question was implying that.  As you say, compilers *are* smart enough to optimize this way, and do so when the function doesn't have a `_Noreturn` attribute.

Comment: @PeterCordes Sorry, but that's exactly what the question was saying. The dummy push being unnecessary was not mentioned at all by the original poster.  I've corrected my post to say "compiler aren't smart enough", as they aren't in this case.  The tail call situation is a different case worth special handling because performance might very well mater.

Comment: Ok, IDK whether the question asker is aware of it or not.  But the RSP adjustment instruction is only there because of the non-tail call.  This explanation still seems a bit like putting the cart before the horse to me.  That RSP adjustment is a side-effect of missing the optimization of treating it as a tailcall, not the other way around, IMO.  With optimization enabled, gcc is perfectly happy to use the stack in a leaf function without modifying RSP (e.g. using the red-zone for `volatile` locals, or a local array it can't optimize away) so I wouldn't say that GCC always needs to align RSP.

Comment: @PeterCordes I never said GCC always needs to align RSP, indeed I explained that GCC (and clang, and ICC) need not.

Comment: I was trying to imagine reasons why you'd think that GCC would have a `sub rsp,8` at all that it would need to undo if it hadn't chosen `call`.  I agree you didn't say that.  I think the "stack alignment is hard" explanation only works as far as saying compilers would have to treat it as a tailcall (where they do know how to get the alignment right), not just a drop-in replacement for `call` with `RSP-=n*16`.  So I think choosing to treat it as a tailcall is the likely sticking point, *not* that they get stuck and can't remove the stack alignment they already pushed.

Comment: So yes, local vars could unnecessarily block this optimization in a function that did *need* some stack space.  And it probably wouldn't be worth having extra code to look for the optimization there.  Especially in a function that makes some calls to normal functions and some paths that lead to calling a `_Noreturn` function.  But that still doesn't explain not tailcalling when that *is* an option.  I suspect it's intentional because noreturn functions include `abort()` and often want to backtrace.

Comment: @PeterCordes Because they'd have to write the code to recognize the _Noreturn case, as it's different than the "return" case, because the later has a return the former doesn't.

Comment: `void` functions that end with a function call do get compiled to a tailcall.  It's not limited to `return foo();` cases.  A non-void function that calls a `_Noreturn` function would be more of a special case, though.  Interesting point.

Comment: @PeterCordes *sigh* void funcitons have a return instruction too.  That should've been obvious.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what context your previous "because" comment was talking about.  I thought you were talking about C `return` statements, not asm instructions or general flow control.  On 2nd look, I think you mean to be able to treat a `_Noreturn` function as a tailcall.  I think I see what you're saying now.  Yeah, call/ret -> jmp could be different from call / unreachable -> jmp in the compiler's flow-control model.  I was mentally short-cutting that and thinking like an asm programmer, not a compiler, I guess. (But `void` functions don't have a `ret` if they end with a `jmp` tailcall.)

Comment: I googled and it is intentional, not because compilers aren't smart enough.  It's exactly because the most common noreturn functions are things like `abort` where we want a stack trace to include the real call site.

Comment: @PeterCordes Note that `abort` isn't the only reason. Richard Henderson's points (1) and (3) in a comment on a GCC bug report support the reasons I gave in my answer. https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=10837#c2  Indeed (3) is the actual reason why it was never implemented in the first place.